# How to save created file to the same project directory? Java

Tags: java, file

Is there any way to save my new File to the same project it is using?
For example I can save here but really want to save it in the project folder.

```
File temp = new File("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\results.csv");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(temp);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save it to the top level package in your project folder (your CLASSPATH). Then you can use `File temp = new File("results.csv");`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path to project directory and then save the file

```
 File temp = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toFile()
```